# Android Geofence addGeofences

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I have a problem with geofencing in Android.
I follow the instructions of https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
I build the list of geofence, I connect with LocationClient and it works and it returns the connection, I can get the last position...
But when I execute:

`mLocationClient.addGeofences(InfoApp.mGeofenceList, mTransitionPendingIntent, this);`

I don't have response in onAddGeofencesResult.
I don't see any message in logcat.

I create the geofence with this code:

```
mUIGeofence1 = new SimpleGeofence(
infoEstablecimiento.getString("_id"),
infoEstablecimiento.getDouble("latitud"),
infoEstablecimiento.getDouble("longitud"),
(float) infoEstablecimiento.getDouble("radio"),
Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE,
// This geofence records only entry transitions with a delay
Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL, loiteringDelay);
```

First I call this function with REQUEST_TYPE.ADD:

```
public static void conexionGeofence(
        REQUEST_TYPE mRequestType,
        Context contexto,
        SlidingFragmentActivity actividad,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionAct,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionListener) {
    // Start a request to add geofences
    /*
     * Test for Google Play services after setting the request type. If
     * Google Play services isn't present, the proper request can be
     * restarted.
     */
    if (!servicesConnected(actividad)) {
        return;
    }
    /*
     * Create a new location client object. Since the current activity class
     * implements ConnectionCallbacks and OnConnectionFailedListener, pass
     * the current activity object as the listener for both parameters
     */
    InfoApp.mLocationClient = new LocationClient(contexto, connectionAct,
            connectionListener);

    // If a request is not already underway
    if (!InfoApp.mInProgress) {
        InfoApp.mRequestType = mRequestType;

        // Indicate that a request is underway
        InfoApp.mInProgress = true;
        // Request a connection from the client to Location Services
        InfoApp.mLocationClient.connect();
    } else {
        /*
         * A request is already underway. You can handle this situation by
         * disconnecting the client, re-setting the flag, and then re-trying
         * the request.
         */
    }
}
```

I received response in onConnected, but when I call addGeofences don't receive any reponse more.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    /*
     * Choose what to do based on the request type set in removeGeofences
     */
    switch (InfoApp.mRequestType) {
    case ADD:
        // Get the PendingIntent for the request
        InfoApp.mTransitionPendingIntent = GeofenceUtils
                .getTransitionPendingIntent();

        Location loc = InfoApp.mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        // Send a request to add the current geofences
        InfoApp.mLocationClient.addGeofences(InfoApp.mGeofenceList,
                InfoApp.mTransitionPendingIntent, this);
        break;

    case REMOVE_LIST:
        InfoApp.mLocationClient.removeGeofences(InfoApp.mGeofencesToRemove,
                this);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you share also InfoApp.java?

Answer (score 0):

Have you waited to call `addGeofences()` until the `LocationClient` is connected?

Comment: Yes, I call addGeofences() in onConnected event. you mean that? Thank you

Comment: yes, of course. If you need more, tell me. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following ADD case:

```
    // Get the PendingIntent for the request
    InfoApp.mTransitionPendingIntent = GeofenceUtils
            .getTransitionPendingIntent();

    Location loc = InfoApp.mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

    // Send a request to add the current geofences
    InfoApp.mLocationClient.addGeofences(InfoApp.mGeofenceList,
            InfoApp.mTransitionPendingIntent, this);
    break;
```

waited to call `addGeofences()` until the `LocationClient` is connected?